# How to run async functions in a loop in typescript?

Tags: typescript, async-await

If I have this

```
class Foo {
    constructor(obj:number) {
         // run "Run"
         // run "Run" after 1 second after each time it finishes
    }
    private async Run(obj:number):Promise<void> {
         // some code does uses await
    }
}
```

when the instance is created, I want it to run `Run`, and when it finishes it waits 1 second and then it runs `Run` again, in an infinite loop, but using `setTimeout`. Also the `Run` doesn't return any value so it can be void.

How can I do this?

Comment: `while (true) { await delay(1000); … }`

Comment: A constructor should not start an asynchronous process.

Answer (score 1):

here is a code with a few helpers allowing you to do that

```
class Foo {
    constructor(obj:number) {
       this.startRunning();
    }
    private async startRunning():Promise<void> {
         for(let i = 0;; i++) {
            await this.Run(i);
            await this.delay(1000);
         }
    }
    private delay(timeout: number): Promise<void> {
      return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, timeout));
    }
    private async Run(obj:number):Promise<void> {
         // some code does uses await
    }
    
}
```

Comment: what if i goes past the max int?

Comment: uh, it won't. `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ` is suuuuper long. earth will be destroyed before you wait for that many ticks